# File modification time is different compared to Python time

Tags: python, linux, unix-timestamp

`time.time()` returns a bigger timestamp than the modification time of a file which was created afterwards. Why?

```
import time
import os
p = '/tmp/a3'
before_creation = time.time()
open(p, 'w')
creation = os.path.getmtime(p)
print(before_creation > creation, before_creation - creation)
print(before_creation, creation)
>>
True 0.005841493606567383
1609357964.7233727 1609357964.7175312
```

Comment: Ask the operating system. It provides both times.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.time) , it says that, "even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second."  So, I think a difference which is less than a second is negligible.